# In search of a symmetric homogeneous graph with a pivotal origin

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, tiling

I'm trying to design a computer game and I need a symmetric homogeneous graph with a pivotal origin which will act as the map of the game (players will walk according to it).

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Let me describe this game:

1. Players can walk on the edges landing on vertices.
2. Blue dot marks the final destination.
3. Yellow dots show stages one prior to final one and they are all of the same value (difficulty level). This goes on as we get farther from the center. In other words the difficulty level drops by the number of edges remaining to the pivot.
4. The purpose of the game is to players fight their path through for the blue dot.

What are desired characteristics of this pattern:

1. It has a central point which can be considered as the final stage.
2. Number of vertices of the same value grows as we get farther from the origin.
3. All the vertices have the same number of neighbors (6, event though the number 6 itself is not important but to keep the game simple, the lower the better).

As perfect as this graph is, it still has got one problem. It's not completely fair. Take vertices 1 and 2 for example. Player 1 has only one path to next level while player two has 2 (one adjacent yellow dot by P1 and two adjacent yellow dots by P2).

Does anyone know of a similar pattern which is also fair?

Comment: Is this a visual pattern you're looking for or a usage pattern?

Comment: Are they any different? You can always use a visual pattern for other purposes! It's an idea that I'm looking for.

Comment: If its' not about a visual pattern specifically I think you've posted to an out-of-your-question-scope Q&A site. This one's about graphic design specifically. And not usability. That's a different site. And **no** visual is not the same as math graphs... I suggest you write your question on **math** site as this seems more of a graph theory problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on this site because it is about mathematics graphs theory.

Comment: I would do that if it's actually off-topic but personally I think it could be in the right place. I mean someone with a good knowledge of visual patterns should be able to answer it!

Comment: Visual patterns or not, this is not a graphic design question but a (visual or not) mathematics graph theory.

Comment: I've used math to create designs before...I don't see why everyone is voting to close this. Not sure why the downvotes are happening either? It's not a bad quality question, even if the community decides it to be off topic.

Comment: @Brendan: Thanks. Originally I posted this question here (instead of a math forum) because I thought members of this forum are familiar with patterns better than a math forum. And I don't expect anyone reinvent a pattern for me, I just was hoping someone would already know such a pattern.

Comment: @Mehran I hope this gets reopened so I can post an answer, but do you think something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bB8iO.png) would work?

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily off-topic, but it's definitely overlapping with the math and with game dev sites, and they will be able to help you more than we can. I'd say it could exist in all those places, but duplicated questions are not encouraged unless each site can give a different perspective. Since the community here seems to be considering this off-topic, I'm migrating to Math. @Brendan, you can still post your solution there.

Comment: @Brendan: Thank you so much man. I really appreciate your time. Thanks for the link too but unfortunately there's a problem with that pattern. It's sort of a fractal which means the outer shapes are the same as inner ones. What I'm looking for, like the example given, should have more number of crossings as we go farther from center.

Comment: @Yisela: I do completely agree with you. This question could be easily categorized as inter-disciplinary and thanks for migrating it here, it's already getting answers.

Answer (score 1):

Does the [penrose tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) satisfy what you're looking for? Various other [aperiodic tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling) may also be of interest.

[image]

(Image courtesy of Wikipedia)

Comment: I wish I understood math, this is awesome.

Comment: @Daniel: As pretty as this tiling is, it doesn't satisfy the conditions. The number of edges ending to vertices are not the same in all of them. I shall also update the question to match math terminology. Thanks for the links they are useful.